# How to fix AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'square'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, keras, attributeerror

I have updated numpy to 1.14.0. I use Windows 10. I tried to run my code and I got this error:

> AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'square'

Here are my imports:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import math
```

Comment: If you called a file `numpy.py`, pick a different name (and delete the corresponding `numpy.pyc` if there is one).

Comment: show the entire code and the entire error

Comment: @user2357112 I did as u said but my new error is :`module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__'`

Comment: I got this error when loading `matplotlib`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I removed numpy.py then updated my numpy and it worked!

Comment: I ran `conda update --all`, `pip uninstall -y numpy`, `pip uninstall -y setuptools`, `pip install setuptools==39.1.0`, and `pip install numpy` and that seemed to solve that error about "'numpy' has no attribute 'square'".

Comment: The above solution works, except that I didn't hardcode the version. uninstalling numpy and scipy, and just re-installing them.