# How to solve the error when importing matplotlib in Anaconda on macOS?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `Python 3.6.5` in `macOs 10.13.6` and I can not import `matplotlib`.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled `matplotlib` with `conda` without results.

```
Python 3.6.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr  6 2018, 13:44:09)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sergiobacelar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from . import cbook
  File "/Users/sergiobacelar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 2640, in <module>
    class _StringFuncParser(object):
  File "/Users/sergiobacelar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 2652, in _StringFuncParser
    _funcs['quadratic'] = _FuncInfo(np.square,
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'square'
```

Comment: The error you get is about numpy, not matplotlib, so maybe you have a version mismatch between the two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'square'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235169/how-to-fix-attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-square)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by  ImportanceOfBeingErnest it seems that matplotlib cannot import numpy, so try to uninstall and reinstall numpy with conda and tell us what you get.
This seems to be a duplicate: [How to fix AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'square'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235169/how-to-fix-attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-square)
Where your problem has been solved ;)

However it seems to me that when installing Anaconda, matplotlib and numpy are both preinstalled. Did you make change is these installations at some point ?

Comment: I uninstalled and installed `numpy` with `conda` but this implied that `matplotlib: 2.2.2-py36_1` is also removed.  After this, I reinstalled `matplotlib`but I got the same error.

Comment: Solved! I had to install `numpy`using `conda install -c anaconda numpy` and not as I have done before simply with `conda install numpy`. I can't understand the reason but now it works.