# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'byte'

Tags: python-3.7

get the error: AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'byte'

I'm new to the python and I just try some code that shows below.
I don't understand why I get this error, I even didn't `import numpy`

```py
import os
import json
import skimage

dataset_dir = "C:\\Users\\LIMU\\PycharmProjects\\test1\\datasets"
json_path = "C:\\Users\\LIMU\\PycharmProjects\\test1\\json"

# 读取json
annotations = json.load(open(os.path.join(json_path, "1.json")))
polygons = annotations['shapes']
image_path = os.path.join(dataset_dir, annotations['imagePath'])
image = skimage.io.imread(image_path)
height, width = image.shape[:2]
```

I expect get the height and width of the image, and the image's path is in the json file. But apparently, I code it wrong.

my English is poor, please bear with me.
thanks in advance.XD

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and solved it by uninstalling numpy and installing it again.
check here also: [How to fix AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'square'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235169/how-to-fix-attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-square)